# TPopupActionBar has no ColorMap property?

Tags: delphi, coding-style

Ok, so I almost have a good looking UI, using TActionManager, TActionMainMenuBars and TToolBar with DrawingStyle as gradient to create a OfficeXP style interface.

I am using a couple of TPopupActionBar popup menus too, but I dont see a ColorMap property. I am using a ColorMap property to change the color of the default XP style color, and also changing the Hot Color of the TToolBar to match the menu.

I now need the TPopupActionBar popup menu to match the menu and toolbar, but how can I do this when I see no way of assigning a ColorMap to it?

Excuse me if this is non trivial, I have looked and cannot see. I also tried at runtime to assign a ColorMap but there doesnt seem to be the property for it?? I can change the Style of the TPopupActionBar, but cannot assign a ColorMap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To assign a ColorMap you can use the [`OnGetControlClass`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ActnPopup.TPopupActionBar.OnGetControlClass) event of the [`TPopupActionBar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ActnPopup.TPopupActionBar) component , then check if the [`PopupMenu`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ActnPopup.TPopupActionBar.PopupMenu) is not nil and finally assign the nested property `ColorMap` of this property.

check this sample.

```
procedure TFormMain.PopupActionBar1GetControlClass(Sender: TCustomActionBar;
  AnItem: TActionClient; var ControlClass: TCustomActionControlClass);
begin
  if Assigned(PopupActionBar1.PopupMenu) then
    PopupActionBar1.PopupMenu.ColorMap:= TwilightColorMap1;
end;
```

check this image which contains a TPopupActionBar with the TwilightColorMap applied

[image]